# How can I get Big Red Racing working on Windows 7?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, big-red-racing

I recently unearthed an old Big Red Racing CD. I'd love to be able to play a game (I used to be *really* good!), but have no idea how to get it working on a modern machine. What should I do?

Comment: DOSBox doesn't work?

Comment: try using a virtual machine for whatever OS you use to play it on

Comment: As @Pubby8 mentioned, DOSBox seems like a sensible solution. Especially considering [it should work](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=834&letter=B).

Comment: thank goodness. A question that uses old-games appropriately ...